# ChefSpec counting resources from included recipe

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chefspec

I have a Chef cookbook (cookbook_alpha::default) that includes another cookbook (cookbook_bravo::default) using `include_recipe 'cookbook_bravo::default'`.

When I'm testing cookbook_alpha using ChefSpec, all of the resources in cookbook_alpha are shown and are tested. But the resources (files, templates, users etc) in cookbook_bravo show up as `Untouched resources` in cookbook_alpha test run. cookbook_bravo has it's own test suites and is covered adequately and I see no need to write duplicate, additional specs in cookbook_alpha simply to cover the resources from cookbook_bravo that are already tested.

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/sethvargo/chefspec#reporting) about the filters to avoid this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your cookbook dependency manager ([Berkshelf](https://github.com/sethvargo/chefspec#berkshelf), [Librarian](https://github.com/sethvargo/chefspec#librarian), none) ChefSpec can determine, if a chef resource call is made outside or inside the current cookbook. (You still may have to stub calls to data bags and thinngs like file system checks in pre-conditionals (`only_if`, `not_if`)).

If you, for whatevery reasons, can't use any of the integration, you still can stub the `include_recipe` call as described in the ReadMe:

https://github.com/sethvargo/chefspec#include_recipe

hope this answers your question.